# Convert multiple returns from a join into a single comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
    r.Name AS Roles
FROM
    Contacts c
    JOIN AspNetUsers u on c.ContactID = u.ContactID
    JOIN AspNetUserRoles ur on u.id = ur.UserId
    JOIN AspNetRoles r on ur.RoleId = r.Id
```

That returns a set something like this:

```
Name        Roles
-----------------------
Bob Jones   Admin
Bob Jones   Agent
Jane Smith  Broker
Jane Smith  Buyer
```

What I would like is this:

```
Name        Roles
-----------------------
Bob Jones   Admin, Agent
Jane Smith  Broker, Buyer
```

I've been playing around with `COALESCE` and `GroupBy`, but I can't seem to get the right combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to place your original query in a cte and then create the final summary

```
;with cte as (
    SELECT
        c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
        r.Name AS Roles
    FROM
        Contacts c
        JOIN AspNetUsers u on c.ContactID = u.ContactID
        JOIN AspNetUserRoles ur on u.id = ur.UserId
        JOIN AspNetRoles r on ur.RoleId = r.Id
)
Select A.Name
      ,Roles = Stuff((Select Distinct ', ' +Roles From cte Where Name=A.Name For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
 From (Select Distinct Name from cte) A
```

Comment: Thanks!  Question... for the same of this post I removed some fields I need in the final result.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to add them in to your query. Suppose I also needed c.ContactID and and c.Email from the Contacts table?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston in final FROM  (Select Distinct ContactID,Name,Email from cte) A

Answer (score 4):

You do this with XML strings, as you can see if you Google "SQL Server string aggregate".

In your case, the query may not be obvious because of the `JOIN`s.  I think this is the best approach:

```
SELECT c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName AS Name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + r.Name
              FROM AspNetUsers u JOIN 
                   AspNetUserRoles ur 
                   ON u.id = ur.UserId JOIN
                   AspNetRoles r 
                   ON ur.RoleId = r.Id
              WHERE c.ContactID = u.ContactID
              FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
             ).VALUE('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 1, '')
             as Roles
FROM Contacts c;
```

The point here is that you don't want to do the aggregation in the outer query, if you can avoid it.  Instead, this uses a correlated subquery.

Note:  This is not *exactly* equivalent because it will return users with no roles.

Comment: Much appreciated!  I am testing.  Seem to be missing a comma or a open or close ( ).

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Removed the extra closing parenthesis, try now.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to retrieve ASPNetUsers with Roles

```
SELECT
 UserName AS Name,
 REPLACE(STUFF(CA.[Role],1,1,''),'"','') AS Roles
FROM
AspNetUsers AS u
CROSS APPLY
(  SELECT
        ', '+r.Name
    FROM 
        AspNetRoles AS r
        INNER JOIN AspNetUserRoles AS ur
        ON  r.Id = ur.RoleId
    WHERE
        u.id = ur.UserId
    FOR XML PATH('')
)CA([Role])
WHERE
  CA.[Role] IS NOT NULL
```